# Change on ngModel reflecting on same ngModel of other browser angular2

Tags: angular, npm, ngmodel

I am new to angular 2 and creating a project on it. I am using npm to run angular 2 application. Currently, I am hosting application on localhost with 3000 port.
 Problem in my project is that when I am visiting same page simultaneously on two different browser say crome and firefox. When I am typing on input on one browser, The other browser also reflecting same text on that input. Even input type password also reflecting same.
I checked in console and it is showing nothing and searched on web but not found any thing near to this problem. Please help me to know:

> why different browser reflecting same text on same ngModel and how to fix it?

Below I pasted gif image to show how things are going wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use Browsersync. lite-server also uses this extention internally.
It is a functionality from Browsersync.

So to avoid this behavior you can open http://localhost:3001 and switch off synchronization option for inputs:

[image]