# Open project in different browsers, manipulation in one browser triggers browser event in all

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

In angular 2 project, when I open my project in different browsers and I change type something in a textbox in one browser, it also automatically enters the same text in all the other opened browses. What could be the reason for this behavior and how can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: That's how it works in development due to the local server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331764/change-on-ngmodel-reflecting-on-same-ngmodel-of-other-browser-angular2

Comment: No, I have also checked in live server giving same problem. I start server by commanding "npm start".

Answer (score 0):

That is because of `node` that you are using for serving your project.if you dont want that. put your project inside your local server(xampp and wampp) directory (htdocs or www) and then visit it from the browser eg. http://localhost/your-project/. This wont happens probably after that.